# Crashes in SPTrack dealloc

Tags: ios, spotify, cocoalibspotify-2.0

Occasionally, I'm seeing crashes originating from the `-dealloc` in `SPTrack`:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0xb1e8ded2
Crashed Thread:  13

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_c.dylib               0x39bb8d5c memset$VARIANT$CortexA9 + 100
1   CoreFoundation                  0x35e1a7fc __CFAllocateObjectArray + 176
2   CoreFoundation                  0x35d62118 _CFXNotificationRemoveObservers + 420
3   Foundation                      0x33834490 -[NSNotificationCenter removeObserver:name:object:] + 228
4   MyAppName                       0x00179fd0 -[SPTrack dealloc] (SPTrack.m:291)
5   MyAppName                       0x0017993a __destroy_helper_block_141 (SPTrack.m:223)
6   libsystem_blocks.dylib          0x352adab0 _Block_release + 220
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x34b064b4 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x34b0b1b8 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 220
9   CoreFoundation                  0x35de9f36 __CFRunLoopRun + 1286
10  CoreFoundation                  0x35d5ceb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
11  CoreFoundation                  0x35d5cd44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
12  GraphicsServices                0x362992e6 GSEventRunModal + 70
13  UIKit                           0x3713b2fc UIApplicationMain + 1116
14  MyAppName                       0x0005e986 main (main.m:14)
15  MyAppName                       0x0001d8e4 start + 36
```

This is what's on #291 in `SPTrack`:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:SPSessionDidUpdateMetadataNotification object:self.session];
```

This generally happens when I bring the app back from the background.

Any ideas to what the cause could be? Is it trying to remove the observer more than once? Or could `self.session` be invalid? (Haven't been able to catch it with the debugger.)

Comment: This looks like a bug unless you're doing something super crazy. I added a commit to CocoaLibSpotify's `dev` branch that makes it more robust if your theory is true (it sounds like a sensible theory). As you said, it's hard to debug without a full trace. I'll keep an eye out for it!

Comment: Thanks. I'll cherry-pick the commit and see if it goes away.

Comment: Haven't seen this error since I updated according to the patch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After [cherry-picking this commit](https://github.com/spotify/cocoalibspotify/commit/f8d63f08e9f04a2005a5ccd846675165bf0dcc6e) in CocoaLibSpotify (as per iKenndac's suggestion), I'm no longer getting these crashes.